# Splitting up a string based on csv

Tags: c#, csv, visual-studio-2012

Below is the code for a button which is meant to parse in a `csv` file and fill a 2X2 table with a client and client name. I've looked online but cannot find a suitable example of what i want to do, using VS 2012 and C# I want to read through the file and only take out and insert the client and client name but at the moment my code simply takes everything within the file.

My intended approach is to take the `csv` and read through it, if a keyword is found; use it and then continue searching, just wondering if anyone could show me how?

For example, I want to search through the `laClient` list and if i find `HTY` i want to then take the next 6 characters after that and continue my search.

```
private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Browse for file
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    //Only show .csv files
    ofd.Filter = "Microsoft Office Excel Comma Separated Values File|*.csv";
    DialogResult result = ofd.ShowDialog();
        
    //If the user selects a valid file 
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        //File is delimited by a comma
        char[] laClientDelim = { ',' };

        //New object for string manipulation
        objStringManipulation = new StringManipulation();
            
        // Parse the csv file
        List<string[]> lsClientList = objStringManipulation.parseCSV(ofd.FileName,  laClientDelim);

        foreach (string[] laClient in lsClientList)
        {
            //Create new object for manipulating the database
            objSqlCommands = new SqlCommands("Client", "ClientName");
            laClient[8].
                

            //Inserts the client info into datbase
            objSqlCommands.sqlCommandInsertorUpdate("INSERT", laClient[0]);
            //Refreshs the Client table on display from the 
            this.clientTableAdapter.Fill(this.ImpDataSet.Client);

            //update the view 
            dgvClientlst.Update(); 
            
        }
    }
}
```

The csv data looks like this (below), due to the poor quality of this layout i've tried to attach a picture for readability but I don't have 10 reputation so I am unable to do so.

> ISBU,ShareName,Status,Share CCY,Benchmark,NAV Freq,CLASSCODE,SIMULATION,HEDGED,FUNDCCY
>
> 1,1,2,Cj0162289439,FGHT Global Funds - Asia incl Korea Equity,Activated,USD,Daily at 5:00pm (CVT),AC,n/a,N,,
>
> 2,1,2,Cj0622164928,FGHT Global Funds - Asia incl Korea Equity,Activated,USD,Daily at 5:00pm (CCT),ACEUR,n/a,N,,
>
> 3,1,2,Cj0212851702,FGHT Global Funds - Asia incl Korea Equity,Activated,USD,Daily at 5:00pm (CST),ACHEUR,n/a,Y,,
>
> 4,1,2,Cj0042850808,FGHT Global Funds - Asia incl Korea Equity,Activated,USD,Daily at 5:00pm (CET),AD,n/a,N,,
>
> 5,1,2,Cj0212851884,FGHT Global Funds - Asia incl Korea Equity,Activated,USD,Daily at 5:00pm (CDT),ADHEUR,n/a,Y,,
>
> 6,1,2,Cj0162849209,FGHT Global Funds - Asia incl Korea Equity,Activated,USD,Daily at 5:00pm (CHT),EC,n/a,N,,
>
> 7,1,2,Cj0622165065,FGHT Global Funds - Asia incl Korea Equity,Non-activated,USD,Daily at 5:00pm (CET),ECEUR,n/a,N,,
>
> 8,1,2,Cj0112316214,FGHT Global Funds - Asia incl Korea Equity,Activated,USD,Daily at 5:00pm (CGT),ED,n/a,N,,
>
> 9,4,2,Cj0162193169,FGHT Global Funds - Asia incl Korea Equity,Activated,USD,Daily at 5:00pm (CBT),IC,n/a,N,,

Comment: Add a sample of the CSV data.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I cant add a file or pic so copy an pasted data in , looks messy though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to read a csv, and get the single values with this code:

```
string[] records = File.ReadAllLines(fileName); // read the file completely line by line

// loop through all lines
foreach (string record in records)
{
    string[] fields = record.Split(splitChar);  // reads all the single values per line. 'splitChar' should be the delimiter.
}
```